# magento2 search_tmp join leads to empty results in category listing

Tags: magento2, collection, sql

I just imported products into fresh `magento2` instance and encountered issue that category product listing block are empty, although the products successfully appear in database . I have debugged `list.phtml` block and dumped the collection query which is:

```
SELECT `e`.*,
           `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
           `price_index`.`price`,
           `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
           `price_index`.`final_price`,
           IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
           `price_index`.`min_price`,
           `price_index`.`max_price`,
           `price_index`.`tier_price`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
    AND cat_index.store_id=1
    AND cat_index.visibility IN(2,
                                4)
    AND cat_index.category_id='31'
    INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id
    AND stock_status_index.website_id = '1'
    AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1
    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
    AND price_index.website_id = '1'
    AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
    INNER JOIN `search_tmp_58171902857f18_28938044` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id
    WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status=1)
    ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 9
```

I tried to run this raw query in in console `mysql` and noticed that it fails on this part:

```
INNER JOIN `search_tmp_58171902857f18_28938044` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id
```

which is probably virtual table

without this `JOIN` query returns collections as expected

any suggestions for directions of debugging would be much appreciated

**PS**
cache is turned off, and I have rebuilt indexes via `bin/magento indexer:reindex`,
the theme is `porto`

Comment: I could not solve it in my store, I also use the porto theme and I have problems when I type something in the search bar, the result is null. Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'search_result.score' in 'order clause' my version of magento is 2.2.2 and already it is in agreement with the alteration of the Magento Master

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To debug this, temporarily change `createTemporaryTable` to `createTable` in

\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorage::createTemporaryTable

```
    $table->setOption('type', 'memory');
    $connection->createTable($table); // changed
    return $table;
}
```

No you will be able to inspect the table with other MySQL tools such as PhpMyAdmin.

In my case the table was empty, so I further debugged:

```
\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Adapter::query
```

and had a look at the $query variable (via Evaluate in the Debugger `(string)$query`)

The lead to the following query:

```
 SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, MAX(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext_scope4` AS `search_index`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `cea` ON search_index.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `capacity_filter` ON search_index.entity_id = capacity_filter.entity_id AND capacity_filter.attribute_id = 142 AND capacity_filter.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `capacity_filter_stock` ON capacity_filter_stock.product_id = capacity_filter.source_id
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON search_index.entity_id = stock_index.product_id AND stock_index.website_id = 0 WHERE (stock_index.stock_status = 1) AND (category_ids_index.category_id = 28) AND (capacity_filter.value = '30' AND capacity_filter_stock.stock_status = 1)) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
 LIMIT 10000
```

There is a wrong store ID in there (1) while I am in store 4 - when changing the store ID to 4, it works.

The query is built in

```
\Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper::buildQuery
```

Goes down to

`\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\FilterMapper\TermDropdownStrategy::apply`

Here is as bug:

```
    $joinCondition = sprintf(
        'search_index.entity_id = %1$s.entity_id AND %1$s.attribute_id = %2$d AND %1$s.store_id = %3$d',
        $alias,
        $attribute->getId(),
        $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getId()
    );
```

Website ID is taken as store ID

The bug is fixed in Magento master:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2c62aa376eeed447e632aedb42085c9d255520df

Comment: great explanation! had to mess with this time to time, thanks for the detailed post !

Answer (score 4):

This was caused improperly build index `catalogsearch_fulltext`, indexer_id in `indexer_state` table was in `working` state, this should be changed to `invalid` and reindexed.

**TIP FOR THOSE WHO STRUGGLING WITH SAME PROBLEM:**

also, temporary table return zero results if products are out of stock or stock qty are 0

Comment: Ahhh I'm glad this worked for you. In my case they are all valid so I set to invalid and reindexed. Still no luck.

Comment: see updated answer