# Is Layered Navigation broken in 2.1.8?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-community

I've just upgraded to Magento 2.1.8 and my layered navigation doesn't seem to be working okay. The number of items under a particular option are incorrect and some of the options are missing. I've double checked the products in the admin section and the data is definitely present.

Did 2.1.8 break layered navigation on the category pages or has something else changed somewhere?

Comment: By 'winnowing', do you mean filtering, layered navigation?

Comment: Yes. the layered navigation look like it is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the upgrade I had to reindex. Have you tried that?

Comment: Do you mean `magento setup:static-content:deploy`? I've done that, but think I need to do it again. Always worth a try.

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex is what I had to do.

Comment: Perfect. That's done it :) Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is broken in some cases, there is a mixup of website and store ID

Fixed in 2.2.0RC

Details:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190817/81

Answer (score 0):

Just see this
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/2c62aa376eeed447e632aedb42085c9d255520df

It have working good for me in magento 2.1.9 as the issue is still persitant

Thanks to marcel!