# No products or too less products shown in Layered Navigation / Filter

Tags: layered-navigation, magento-2.1.8

We are using Magento 2.1.8 and believe this worked in Magento 2.1.7 (but the bug may also been introduced sometime else).

When clicking a filter in the shop category, we get the message "We can't find products matching the selection."

We already reindexed and cleared the cache.

We use the Wyomind_ElasticSearch module but already disabled it and have the same result. But after enabling it back and reindexing, we *sometimes* see one product (which should be more) in the filtered category. Interestingly, the product count shows "4 items", even only 1 is shown.

How can this be debugged?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem and at the moment I'm working on it.

As a quick fix, I changed the following line :

```
)->join(                                                                                                                                                                     
    ['cpa' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],                                                                                                                         
    'cpe.' . $aiField . ' = cpa.' . $aiField,                                                                                                                                
    ['store_id', 'value']
```

with the following :

```
)->join(                                                                                                                                                                     
    ['cpa' => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],                                                                                                                         
    'cpe.' . $aiField . ' = cpa.' . 'row_id' //$aiField,                                                                                                                                
    ['store_id', 'value']
```

And it's working fine.
If I'll not find any collateral error I'll create a module to avoid to edit core files.

The file is **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php** and the **line 1037**

The problem I'm trying to fix at the moment is related with the filters in the category page which for some reason is not showing any product.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in another question
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190817/81

It seems to be a bug in 2.1.8

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue after upgrading to 2.1.8 from 2.1.7 the filters would return no results and [this](https://technotab.com/magento-2-1-8-layered-navigation-bug-fix) is how we fixed it.