# Product attribute in filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, layered-navigation

My issue is quite simple to resume :

I have 2 products attribute. One of them is already appearing in my filter front panel. The other is not.

I have almost the same configuration for both of them.
What's tilting me is that I think the configuration is kind of ignored (indeed with that configuration I don't think neither of these attributes should be added to the filter panel) but one is.

As you can see here is what I have under `Product Attributes`

[image: product attributes]

The first one is already appearing in filter, but not the second one.

[image: front filter]

Inside their configuration everything is the same

So my issue is : Why the second one isn't appearing (I have enought data to make it appear, so it's not because I don't have any products with that attributes).
Is there some place in the code where I can check what is going on ?

First attributes properties (the second one is the exact same except he has system values).

[image: properties part 1]

[image: properties part 2]

[image: properties storefront]

Attributes creation :

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);  

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'longueur_tasse_vertuo', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Longueur de tasse Vertuo',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Cpy\Catalog\Model\Config\Product\CupSizeVertuooption',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'group' => '',
            'sort_order' => 203,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true
        ]
    );
```

The sources file defines (which are the default system values.

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $this->_options = [];
    $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Espresso', 'value' => '1'];
    $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Double Espresso', 'value' => '2'];
    $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Gran Lungo', 'value' => '3'];
    $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Mug', 'value' => '4'];
    $this->_options[] = ['label' => 'Alto', 'value' => '5'];

    return $this->_options;
}
```

I can't find any setup for the first one that is already appearing.

Also if It can help I have this in a 'product_cofee.xml' layout

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.cafe.cupsize" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cafe/cup-size.phtml" before="product.info.price" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getLongueurTasse</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">longueur_tasse</argument>
        <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-nespresso-cupsize</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Taille des tasses :</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="nespresso-cupsize"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.cafe.cupsize.vertuo" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/cafe/vertuo/cup-size.phtml" before="product.info.price" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getLongueurTasseVertuo</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">longueur_tasse_vertuo</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-nespresso-cupsize-vertuo</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Taille des tasses :</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="nespresso-cupsize"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

#EDIT

My query

```
2020-07-24T08:37:17+00:00 INFO (6): SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.*, IFNULL(al.value, main_table.frontend_label) AS `store_label` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_label` AS `al` ON al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = 7 WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 4) AND (`additional_table`.`is_filterable` > 0) ORDER BY position ASC
```

#EDIT Add second request

```
2020-07-24T13:19:40+00:00 INFO (6): longueur_tasse
2020-07-24T13:19:40+00:00 INFO (6): SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status_index`.`is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store7` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=7 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=43
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '8' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON product.entity_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_8` AS `stock_status_index` ON product.sku = stock_status_index.sku
 INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5f1adfebb39791_19171320` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` asc, `e`.`entity_id` DESC, `cat_index`.`position` asc
 LIMIT 10

2020-07-24T13:19:40+00:00 INFO (6): longueur_tasse_vertuo
2020-07-24T13:19:40+00:00 INFO (6): SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `stock_status_index`.`is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store7` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=7 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=43
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '8' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product` ON product.entity_id = e.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `inventory_stock_8` AS `stock_status_index` ON product.sku = stock_status_index.sku
 INNER JOIN `search_tmp_5f1adfebb39791_19171320` AS `search_result` ON e.entity_id = search_result.entity_id ORDER BY `cat_index`.`position` asc, `e`.`entity_id` DESC, `cat_index`.`position` asc
 LIMIT 10
```

EDIT 18/08 :

I've been finding the class responsible for the missing data
It's `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder`

And here is the method

```
public function build(
    DataProviderInterface $dataProvider,
    array $dimensions,
    RequestBucketInterface $bucket,
    Table $entityIdsTable
) {
    $metrics = $this->metricsBuilder->build($bucket);

    $select = $dataProvider->getDataSet($bucket, $dimensions, $entityIdsTable);
    $select->columns($metrics);
    $select->group(RequestBucketInterface::FIELD_VALUE);

    if($bucket->getName() === 'longueur_tasse_vertuo_bucket' || $bucket->getName() === 'longueur_tasse_bucket'){
        var_dump($bucket->getName());
        var_dump($dataProvider->execute($select));
    }
    return $dataProvider->execute($select);
}
```

With `longueur_tasse_bucket` I'll have the result while with `longueur_tasse_vertuo_bucket` I won't have anything

Comment: one is system whilst the other is not.. just to be picky. We don't see their type, is one dropdown and the other now, you might want to add 2 screenshot of the attributes' details

Comment: Is it possible to send the setup script that creates them, then I'd be able to imitate this and simulate on my local?

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I've been adding as much info as I can found about these two attributes. Hope it can help.

Comment: the temp table is there because you use the search, I was under the impression we do want category layer?

Comment: It's indeed a category `website/my-page` with 2 sub category loaded as `website/my-page#sub_cat1` in it and I want to get the attribute inside the filter from this page.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143420/magento2-search-tmp-join-leads-to-empty-results-in-category-listing.. I ma now a bit short in the day to help more, but this do.. if you want more help, look like bounty will come next, no doubt you will receive a lot of feedback as it is quite common subject

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your time I will keep track of my results.
Looks like I'm getting the same results for the request on both attributes

Comment: Hi @HerveTribouilloy, after a few days and with a fresh mind I went once again into this issue. I've just been ending up by finding the class responsible of the association between the filter and his values. The class is `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder\Term`. So now I have to see if the issue comes from the semect or from the dataProvider. I'll for sure keep you in touch with the results once I'll have the last word, and I will, I hope !

Comment: I all my time spent was followed up this way, I'd be over the moon, thanks, very interesting findings

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy So analysing the request end up to a new findings, the request make an inner join between a set of ids from the tmp table and the table `catalog_product_index_eav`. When I look into that specific table, I can see there is no line matching the `longueur_tasse_vertuo` while there is for `longueur_tasse`. So this is why the filter is fucked up....it brings a new issue that is : why isn't the lines properly inserted when a product is saved.

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I got it...eventually I end up looking into the Indexer. The evil class is `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php` inside the method `_getIndexableAttributes` we can see the where condition for multiselect only takes the type varchar while my type was text. So at the end, all what was needed was changing the  attribute type from text to varchar and then play the indexer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue belongs to the class `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php`

The method

```
protected function _getIndexableAttributes($multiSelect)
{
    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
        ['ca' => $this->getTable('catalog_eav_attribute')],
        'attribute_id'
    )->join(
        ['ea' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
        'ca.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id',
        []
    )->where(
        $this->_getIndexableAttributesCondition()
    );

    if ($multiSelect == true) {
        $select->where('ea.backend_type = ?', 'varchar')->where('ea.frontend_input = ?', 'multiselect');
    } else {
        $select->where('ea.backend_type = ?', 'int')->where('ea.frontend_input IN( ? )', ['select', 'boolean']);
    }
    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($select);
}
```

For multiselect, the required type was varchar while my attribute had a type text.

So all we have to do is to change the attribute type to varchar and then play the indexer once again to get the association geing written in the table `catalog_product_index_eav` making it possible to be appearing in the filter.

This is for the quick and immediate fix. In the same time, I send the issue to magento to make this multiselect where condition be able to read both text and varchar type, feel free to check it : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29676

Comment: good stamina @Claims, you've deserved a thumb up.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem the one that is product attribute that is system does not want to be in the layer.

I will look into it now. Having said that, one would think it might be worth creating a new product attribute identical to the no system one and then 'do assign your data to the new attribute and refresh index..'

that should be a quick win, if you want to do this and you miss a script to update the attribute, I surely can provide you with this script

Comment: Sadly the system attributes is already appearing in too much code to make such a change at this moment, but indeed it would do the trick I guess. Still I want to find a way to get the system attribute to be added to the layout.

Comment: np, let's give it a go as it is

Comment: I've been investigating a little more.

Looks like in my LayerredNavigation view template I have this condition `if($filter->getItemsCount())` and for the specific attribute items count return 0 (while it shouldn't) may be there is an issue on the setup script which do not add the corresponding items.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some log at the function `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::getList`

this is temporary and therefore can be in the vendor folder directly.

The log we want to use is to know what query runs when the layer filters are pulled in the block `\Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation`

put the lines below just above the line `$collection->load();`

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/layerdebug.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
```

My query on my system is:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.*, IFNULL(al.value, main_table.frontend_label) AS `store_label` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_label` AS `al` ON al.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND al.store_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 4) AND (`additional_table`.`is_filterable` > 0)
```

Once we will know your query, it is likely we will understand why your first system product attribute is not with us.

Step 2: if the above returns the attribute, at this point we want to check if the attributes has some options to render:

same process as above can apply to troubleshoot, you may go to the function \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute::_getItemsData

and put the log just above this line

```
$isAttributeFilterable =
            $this->getAttributeIsFilterable($attribute) === static::ATTRIBUTE_OPTIONS_ONLY_WITH_RESULTS;



$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/layerdebug.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($productCollection->getSelect()->__toString());
```

then at this point, everything should come together. Of course, the query may be big but essentially, you are within the bone of the feature.. and then there is nothing deeper.. so we better have to find from here

Comment: I've been adding my query at the end of the issue. Looks like the query is the same as your except I am on a different store

Comment: can't see any mention of backend_type anywhere in your question?

Comment: just updated my answer. Do think of removing your comments once we are done with this as otherwise it wastes time of people who review stackexchange content

Comment: Issue updated with the request from both attributes, but the table is I think some kind of temp view wich no longer exists outside the code execution. So I can't really check by myself what this is returning.